# What upgrades, quests, wonders, and/or buildings increase the number of trade routes?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Beyond earth, the [Autoplant](http://www.ign.com/wikis/civ-beyond-earth/Autoplant) quest decision will allow a city to have one more trade route than the normal 2.  (Update:  The autoplant no longer gives this quest bonus)
[image: autoplant]
The trade routes in Beyond Earth seem to be much more numerous and thus powerful than they were in Civ 5, so that leads me wondering: What are the other ways to increase the number of trade routes available?

What are all the different ways to increase the number of trade routes in Beyond Earth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found 2 ways to increase the number of trade routes:

- The [Trade Depot Building](http://civilizationbeyondearth.gamepedia.com/Trade_Depot)(of course)
- The [Polystralia faction](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Polystralia_(CivBE)) (Plus two trade routes in the capital)
  [image: polystralia]
- As aslum notes, now trades routes scale with city size: "At population 10 you get 2 routes and at 22 you get a third. Not sure if/when you get a 4th from Trade Depot."

Comment: I think you've covered it. If you find another one, be sure to update your answer and let everyone know! :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning in your answer but if you have a trade depot, the size of your city can increase the number of trade routes! At population 10 you get 2 routes and at 22 you get a third. Not sure if/when you get a 4th from Trade Depot.

Comment: @aslum - Your right, my wife noticed this the other day, I updated my answer, with a reference to your comment.  You can get a 4th one I think but the size is really large, if I recall correctly.